# Load XML into MySQL

Tags: xml, mysql

Managed to obtain a complete XML file with database information and data.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<mysqldump xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<database name="bbdb">
...
```

It was created with mysqldump. But I cannot find a way to load the xml file into an empty database. I looked and tried a lot but so far it yielded no results.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try [LOAD XML](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/load-xml.html) statement ? Available since MySQL 5.2

Comment: Problem mentioned above. I do not have the tables. It's all in the xml file.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check [LOAD XML](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/load-xml.html)? Per the manual: The LOAD XML statement reads data from an XML file into a table

Comment: Yes but the problem is, that I do not have any tables. It is all in the XML file. Now I can go manually through the xml file and figure out which tables to create but thats an awful lot of work. I mean if mysql can export it completely shouldnt it be able to import it completely as well?

Comment: I suppose, but its not "IMPORT XML", it's LOAD XML, so to my knowledge, you'll have to create the table.  I do stand to be corrected, but I don't think that can happen.